# Debian Startup Script Will Not Start

Tags: linux, bash, debian, init, init.d

I was creating a startup BASH script, when I was given an error similar to:

```
The script is missing LSB tags
```

So I went and put in some LSB tags, but it still does not start on startup. The script works perfectly if I start it manually

```
# /etc/init.d/myscript
```

It is a very simple script that is intended to startup a PERL script in the same folder (/etc/init.d/fcgiwrap.pl).

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
touch /var/lock/fcgiwrap
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap.pl"
    /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap.pl
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "You can't stop this service. Consider deleting it"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/blah {start}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: so what is the question? who/what is running the script to make it `start`?

Comment: The script is supposed to run on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the script to do things "at startup," you need to run commands (`rc.d`) rules for it. Otherwise it is just a script floating in `/etc/init.d`.

For a guide on `rc.d`, checkout https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian , and look particularly for the `update-rc.d` command.

Also, if you're going to use an LSB style header, you might as well actually fill out the values to have meaning, instead of leaving those defaults.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have done more research on LSB tags instead of just copying and pasting those in.